# Ubuntu 14.04 Ralink RT 3290 wireless lan hard blocked

Tags: wireless, 14.04, ralink

```
$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ lspci | grep Wireless
03:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

$ uname -a
Linux ASUS-X75VC 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

**UPD:**

```
$ sudo rfkill block wifi
$ rfkill list 
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
$ sudo rfkill unblock wifi
$ rfkill list 
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Here is the [solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558 "solution"). You may just have to adapt the driver name but that should be close.

Comment: @AdrienHorgnies have no idea how to adapt it

Answer (score 1):

My problem is fixed by the command:

```
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf
```

Comment: What does this command do? It would be better to edit your answer and add some explanation on how this command works.

Comment: ⁺¹, this fixed the problem on Asus x75V. The purpose of the option [is to enable Fn+F2 combination](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2173539) *(I did use «1» value, like in the answer)*. What's interesting, however, is that it didn't fix the problem with Fn+F2 for that Asus, but *Hard blocked* upon boot changed its value to «no», thus getting WiFi problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Acccording to your terminal reply your "phy0: Wireless LAN"'s hard drive is block. if you want to unblock it just press your wireless shortcut key on you keyboard. Example mine is Fn+f2 on my asus laptop.
Hope it can solve your problem, And have a nice day.

Comment: I tried. Doesn't work for me. Perhaps, I should close theme, because it is partly outdated, I have clean 14.04.2 and didn't try to fix WIFI yet.