# Flight mode is turned ON and I am unable to turn it off

Tags: wireless, 20.04, network-manager

I installed Ubuntu 20.4 recently. I am able to access internet via LAN but not via Wi-Fi. The flight mode is turned ON and I am unable to turn it off. The logs say that it's hard blocked.

Here is the output of `lspci`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
02:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
```

Output of `rfkill list all`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

I have also tried `rfkill unblock all`.

Comment: Please add the output of `rfkill list all` in your question.

Comment: You have not mentioned vendor and version of your wifi hardware. Can you please provide output of `lspci`?

Comment: yes .. Tried ,no luck

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 14.04 Ralink RT 3290 wireless lan hard blocked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459436/ubuntu-14-04-ralink-rt-3290-wireless-lan-hard-blocked)

Comment: What model is the laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your hardware information you may follow [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459436/ubuntu-14-04-ralink-rt-3290-wireless-lan-hard-blocked).

Also, have you tried `sudo rfkill unblock all`?

If that works, I would suggest marking this question as duplicate.

Comment: No it is not working .Tried sudo rfkill unblock all

Comment: Have you tried the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459436/ubuntu-14-04-ralink-rt-3290-wireless-lan-hard-blocked) provided?